# Re-sync folders via command line

Tags: advanced-installer

I am currently working out how best to go about syncing files in my folders which will be included in my installer.

It works fine through the interface, but doesn't seem to work out well when doing it through the command line.

My folder structure is essentially:

- Root

  - Installer Config
  - My code 1
  - My code 2

My installer is to set up my two code folders when installed. Like I mentioned, I have this set up working for building the installer through the interface.
In my project, I have My code 1 and My code 2 folders set as sync folders in the Files and Folders section.

In the Installer Config folder, I am running a couple of scripts which essentially boil down to a batch file which does:

```
"AdvancedInstaller.com" /loadpathvars PathVariables.xml
"AdvancedInstaller.com" /execute myproject.aip commands.txt
```

and my commands.txt which does:

```
;aic
ResetSync APPDIR\mycode1
ResetSync APPDIR\mycode2
Save
Rebuild
```

When the ResetSync calls are made, I get the error: Folder not synchronized: APPDIR\mycode1. but when I just hit refresh in the Files and Folders section in interface, it works fine.

To create this error I add a new file to the 'My code 1' folder. Run the scripts, and I get the 'Folder not synchronized' error.

Answer (score 1):

Solved on [Advanced Installer forums.](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=26236)